# android sherlock actionbar menu item going wrong

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, menuitem, android-version

as the title suggest, I am getting a  problem with the action Bar since i have recently installed android Api 22 under  eclipse and jdk-7u76-windows-i586. Before the action Bar keep to display the icon with sdk version 7 and higher. But now icon is displayed only with sdk version 11 and higher,did I miss something or am I just blind?, here are the menu XML file and a screen shot:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/share"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_group"
      android:title="share info"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Good i finally find the answer. But what is strange is that the code use to work before the sdk update:Means that this newer version of sdk has a good improvement about XML files. Then more errors get detected by the oldest versions.
**Now how to solve problem with sherlock action Bar menu item?**

- if you want it to work for android api 11 and higher(Android 4.x or 5.x )
  simply add this piece of code: 
      Create a file in **rsc/menu/** eg:menu.xml 
  Now put:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     >

  <item 
  android:id="@+id/send"
  android:title="@string/Send"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new_event"
  android:showAsAction="ifRoom" 
  />

   </menu>
  ```

  And add a sample styles:in  rsc/values/ :

  ```
     <style name="AppTheme"    
    parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"  />

     </resources>
  ```

This in your Activity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.men, menu);


       return true;
    }
```

- if you want it to work for android api 7 to 10(Android 2.x to Android 3.x) 
  use something like this one in you class Activity:

  ```
    THEME == R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light;

    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){



     boolean isLight = THEME == R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light;

    menu.add(R.string.Send)

   .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_action_group : 

      R.drawable.ic_action_person)
       .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

     menu.add(R.id.get)
                .setIcon(isLight ?   

    R.drawable.ic_action_chat:          
     R.drawable.ic_action_chat)
         .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM |           

        MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

      menu.add("Refresh")
      .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_action_time :        

      R.drawable.ic_action_volume_on)
       .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM |   
       MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    return true;
            }
  ```

  To respond to a click use somthing like this:

  ```
  @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


       if (item.toString()==getString(R.string.Send)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got click: " + item,       
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
  ```

  And add a sample styles:in **src/values/**:

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <resources>
  <style name="Theme.Styled"   

  parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">

  <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>

  <item      
  name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
       </style>

   <style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" 

              parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

  <item name="background">@drawable/bg_striped</item>
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_striped</item>

  <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
  <item         
  name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
   </style>
   </resources>
  ```